# One Click Manual Update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

Hey I wanted to ask would it be possible to run C#'s ClickOnce update and after that update run my own exe that updates the database file. Right now ClickOnce update will overwrite everything, but I want to append information to the database not overwrite the database.

So the idea would look like:

1. User starts the program
2. ClickOnce update installs the update
3. ClickOnce update opens my updater.exe file that will update the database
4. Everything is done
5. Program starts again

Comment: Does the DB itself exist separately, or is it distributed as a file within the ClickOnce package?

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you could really do with providing more information... what is this `updater.exe`? How does the `ClickOnce` update overwrite everything in your database?

I don't think that you can tell the `ClickOnce` update functionality to run an executable as part of the update, but you can reference your `updater.exe` in the `Application Files` window.

> Startup Project Properties > Publish Tab > Application Files Button

Set your `Publish Status` column to `Include (Auto)`, `Download Group` column to `(Required)` and `hash` column  to `Include`.

Doing this will ensure that the latest version of your `updater.exe` file is installed to your installation directory. From there, you can access and run your `updater.exe` file from your `ClickOnce` application.

Comment: Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.downloadfilegroup.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak58kz04.aspx which might be of interest.

Comment: Yes, everything is good.. all files are installed. BUT it overwrites all the files that are previously installed - when it updates. My database is a text file which contains JSON. So.. when user updates the software via ClickOnce.. the database will be overwritten by the database file that comes from the server.. So I would like to prevent it by executing my updater.exe file after the ClickOnce update is done.. so I can download that database file from the server.. take the information from it and merge it with existing database. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I was thinking right now, maybe I could exclude the server's database file.. and ummm.. in the config maybe set like.. updated=1. So when the program starts.. it checks if system was updated previously.. and then it runs updater.exe by itself which processes everything.

Comment: That sounds like a plan. You can also use user scoped settings to signify whether the database file will need to be updated. See [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=VS.80).aspx) for an example of this.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I'm using an empty "update" file which will be always downloaded when update has been done.. and then when program starts up.. a check will be done if that file exists.. if it does, database will be processed and if it doesn't it just runs normally.